# Algorithm for ‘spreading` sum in Hash

Tags: ruby

I have this greedy algorithm :

```
  banknotes = { 5 => 6, 10 => 7, 20 => 8, 50 => 9 }
  amount = 335
  a = CardCalculation.new(banknotes: banknotes)
  a.greedy_alg( amount: amount )

  class CardCalculation
     def greedy_alg( amount )
       result = {}
        banknotes.each do | face, value |
         needed_value = amount - hash_summator( result )
         quantity     = ( needed_value / face )
         quantity     = value if quantity > value
         result[face] = quantity
       end
      result
    end

    def hash_summator(hash)
      hash.inject(0){|memo, (k, v)| memo += k * v}
    end
```

and in a result I see

```
    result = { 50 => 6, 20 => 1, 10 => 1, 5 => 1 }
```

how you can see, I took 335 (amount:), went through the hash and selected the maximum from each key and its value.

but now I need ‘spreading’ algorithm, I need this result, for example:

```
    result = { 50 => 4, 20 => 4, 10 => 4, 5 => 3}
```

I need the middle number of each key .. I have thoughts about the loop but maybe someone has ideas?

Comment: Like the median value for each?

Comment: yeah.. you are right

Comment: To begin a question with (sic), "I have the following code:", is a time-waster for readers, and by extension, a motivator for them to pass over your question. That's because they have not told what the problem is that the code is intended to solve. I assume it is something like, "Given specified numbers of banknotes of different denominations, we wish to find a combination of notes that totals a given amount." It would be very helpful to begin the question with something like that. Incidentally, I expect this is an NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution could be a starting point, I didn't test for avoiding infinite loop:

```
banknotes = { 5 => 6, 10 => 7, 20 => 8, 50 => 9 }
amount = 335

min = banknotes.keys.min
init_avg = amount / banknotes.keys.sum # calculate the initial average
result = banknotes.transform_values { init_avg } # initialize with average
delta = amount - result.sum { |k,v| k * v }

if delta > 0 # start distribution
  loop do
    banknotes.keys.reverse_each do |val|
      if delta - val >= 0 and result[val] + 1 < banknotes[val]
        delta -= val
        result[val] += 1
      end
    end
    break if delta < min
  end
end

result
#=> {5=>3, 10=>4, 20=>4, 50=>4}
```

Comment: Your way is just great! It works great! Thanks for the help iGian!

Comment: but I see one mistake ... it can take more values ​​than there are in ... if I have {100=>1, 50=>9, 20=>8, 10=>7, 5=>6} and give - amount = 615  it  givves me result {100=>3, 50=>4, 20=>3, 10=>4, 5=>3}  but I havnt 100 => 3 only 100=> 1  ... but your going great for starting this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

finished version

```
   banknotes = {5 => 10, 10 => 10, 20 => 10, 50 => 10, 100 => 5}
   amount = 435



def spreaded_alg(amount)
   validate_money!(amount: amount)
   min    = banknotes.keys.min
   avg    = amount / banknotes.keys.sum.round(0)
   result = banknotes.transform_values {avg}
   delta  = amount - result.sum {|k, v| k * v}

if delta > 0
  loop do
    banknotes.keys.each do |value|
      if delta - value >= 0 && result[value] > banknotes[value]
        delta += value
        result[value] -= 1
      end
      if delta - value >= 0 && result[value] + 1 <= banknotes[value]
        delta -= value
        result[value] += 1
      end
    end
    break if delta < min
  end
end
result
end
```